# Is it "neither do" or "neither does"?

Tags: word-usage, subject-verb-agreement

Is it:

> "Neither of my brothers **do** anything to help my parents."

or

> "Neither of my brothers **does** anything to help my parents."

Both sound right to me and I'm not sure which is right.

Comment: Because you've chosen the plural in *brothers* I would stick with the plural verb, *do*.  You could write the sentence in the singular, "Neither brother does anything..." and it would work as well.

Comment: @JasonPatterson- But the fully non-elided phrase is: "Neither *one* of my brothers does anything..." which makes the conjugation clearer.

Comment: For more on this confusing subject, you could visit (on ELU): [_here_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47999/neither-is-or-neither-are), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87925/neither-of-you-understands-him-as-i-do), or [_here_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are). Also, [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87925/neither-of-you-understands-him-as-i-do/87933#87933) essentially says either could be used in conversation, even if one is more "formally" correct from a grammar perspective.

Comment: "Neither" is an distributive pronoun which refer to persons or thing one at a time.For this reason they are always followed singular verb.

Comment: @J.R. Hmmm. One can't be more correct from a formal grammar perspective. If we use both they're both correct. One grammar *authority* might be more correct than the other though (if it says that both are correct)! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria - Your beef is with Barrie England, not with me. Read the answer there. Given his [background](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/12952/barrie-england), though, I enter into disagreements with B.E. very carefully.

Comment: @J.R. I don't have a beef (I'm a veggie!), I have a mantra! I just use every opportunity to air it :) I couldn't see an answer from Barry there though ...

Comment: @Arau - Did you click on the link that says "This answer"? That goes straight to the answer I reference. Also note the scare quotes I put around "formally". We probably agree on this more than onlookers might think.

Comment: @J.R. I think our views are identical, more or less! Didn't realise that that was a different link from the rest of the blue there!

Comment: @Arau - The blue there actually links to three different questions, and then the answer to one of those questions.